# How to get output as a list after removing the duplicates in list?

Tags: python

Below is the Python program to remove the duplicate IP addresses in a list:

```
dup_ip = ['1.1.1.1','2.1.1.1','1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3','2.1.1.1','1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3',]
empty_list=[]
for i in dup_ip:
    if i not in empty_list:
        empty_list.append(i)
        print i
```

I am getting output as shown below:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop>python dup_list.py
1.1.1.1
2.1.1.1
3.3.3.3

C:\Users\test\Desktop>
```

But I want to get output also as a list as shown below:

```
['1.1.1.1', '2.1.1.1','3.3.3.3']
```

How to do this?

Comment: Add `print empty_list` at the end of the program.

Comment: You can also use `list(set(dup_ip))`, as a set can't contain duplicates. You can also omit the `list()`

Comment: *"get output"* where? Just see it on the command line? Or do you want to pass it on somewhere for further processing? Is this in a function?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Thanks print empty_list works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can simply print the `empty_list` or a better way is to is to transform the original `dup_ip` to a `set` and then back to a `list` if needed:

```
>>> dup_ip  = ['1.1.1.1', '2.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3', '2.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '3.3.3.3']
>>> unique_ip = list(set(dup_ip))
>>> print unique_ip
['2.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '3.3.3.3']
```

Comment: I would stay at type `set` to be sure that it will have unique entries in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're printing each element in the inner loop, right after you add it. To print the list all at once you need to print the entire list after everything has been added. So:

```
dup_ip = ['1.1.1.1','2.1.1.1','1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3','2.1.1.1','1.1.1.1','3.3.3.3',]
empty_list=[]
for i in dup_ip:
    if i not in empty_list:
        empty_list.append(i)
print empty_list
```

That will give you the output as a list, as you want.